# Unmarshal a single element list fails

Tags: jaxb, eclipselink, jax-rs, glassfish-3, moxy

I'm running a sample (which i can't find anymore) from [Blaise Doughans blog](http://blog.bdoughan.com) on Glassfish 3 using EclipseLink 2.5 MOXy for JAXB service.

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Company {

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="employees")
    @XmlElement(name = "employee", type=Employee.class)
    private List<Employee> employees;
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Employee {
    private String id;
    private String name;
}
```

I added some annotations to the classes, to produce the desired json structure:

```
{
  "employees": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Jane Doe",
      "report": []
    }
  ]
}
```

When i try to unmarshal this JSON it sadly fails, returning an object with an empty employees list.
Adding another element to the JSON list OR removing the `@XmlElementWrapper` works.
But i want the key element to be named `employees`, so i have to use the wrapper annotation, or not?

Edit:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        HashSet<Class<?>> set = new HashSet<Class<?>>(2);
        set.add(MOXyJsonProvider.class);
        set.add(Index.class);
        return set;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        MOXyJsonProvider moxyJsonProvider = new MOXyJsonProvider();

        moxyJsonProvider.setAttributePrefix("@");
        moxyJsonProvider.setFormattedOutput(true);
        moxyJsonProvider.setIncludeRoot(false);
        moxyJsonProvider.setMarshalEmptyCollections(true);
        moxyJsonProvider.setValueWrapper("$");
        moxyJsonProvider.setWrapperAsArrayName(true);

        HashSet<Object> set = new HashSet<Object>(1);
        set.add(moxyJsonProvider);
        return set;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have confirmed the issue that you are seeing and have opened the following bug:

- http://bugs.eclipse.org/411001

**UPDATE**

The fix for this issue has been checked into the EclipseLink 2.5.1 and 2.6.0 streams.  You can get the fix in the corresponding nightly builds from the following link starting June 19, 2013:

- http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/nightly.php

Comment: Thanks. So i could grab todays nightly build to get the fixed version?

Comment: @Imperative - I will put the fix in today and tomorrow you will be  able to grab the June 19 nightly build.  It is normally available in the morning eastern time.